# C# DataGridView суммирование отмеченых значений

Tags: checkbox, datagridview

Всем привет.
Как суммировать мне нужные ячейки. Есть 2 варианта. Если помечена строка через checkBox то тогда значение из тех строк нужно суммировать. Или если в определённом столбике есть значение Х то тогда значение из тех строк нужно суммировать.

Вот мои варианты. Все не рабочие.

1. где checkbox отмечен:

   ```
      List<int> Percentage01 = new List<int>();
       foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)                
           if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells["check"].Value))
           {                    
               item.Cells["SSCC"].Value = txt_naujas_sscc.Text.ToString();                   
               Percentage01.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["QuantityDespatched"].Value)); 
           } 
       int s1 = 0; 
       for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
       {
           s1 = Percentage01[i] + Percentage01[i + 1]; 
       }
             txt_sscc_pre_ska.Text = s1.ToString(); 
       txt_sscc_pre_ska.Text = s1.ToString();
   ```
2. где значение из DataGridView равно значению из TextBox: суммирует весь столбик, а нужно только те значение определённые значения:

   ```
           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           if (row.Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text)
           {
               int sum = 0;
               for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
               {
                   sum = sum + int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
               }
               txt_sscc_pre_ska.Text = sum.ToString();
           }

       }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells["check"].Value))
    {
         sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["QuantityDespatched"].Value);
    }
}
```

либо можно упростить с использованием System.Linq

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows.Where(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.Cells["check"].Value)))
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["QuantityDespatched"].Value);
}
```

2)

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Value);
    }
}
```

либо можно упростить с использованием System.Linq

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Where(c => c.Cells["SSCC"].Value.ToString() == txt_naujas_sscc.Text))
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Value);
}
```